# Troubleshooting issue with nginx

Tags: nginx, centos

Yesterday, the server worked, but now the url that used to work gives me:

```
404 Not Found
nginx
```

I am using Linux version 2.6.32-754.35.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-02.bsys.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-23) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Sat Nov 7 12:42:14 UTC 2020

The access log gives me a lot of garbage like:

```
Â@{¿â°•‚¹{÷‘„ÄJDFEp!…XD]q1QAñëM!§›a8©¢„´ÑduÛr,çõMjÖ:ç,76·ÇÌ;ˆÙÔA¢pn-)Ë
¦ó"Ëöš¦–11úU¸Û÷+ ÅÄ#t ±#|;Àø~o|å÷exÉØ¤dôËÂ-C4áâ1ó‡K;Àäüh¯^¦–˜Lª3RFaSŸêGøgÝk$z?2ª®ŽÃ
```

I see error logs but nothing came up in the last 5 days, the error log files weren't modified in the last 5 days, so I am not sure what I need to check beside that.

I remember I had some issues with varnish, I think before and after a reboot I was able to solve it, but a reboot didn't do anything.

One thing I saw is inside the php-fpm logs:

```
[05-Jan-2022 10:40:26] NOTICE: finished trace of 8276
[05-Jan-2022 10:40:29] WARNING: [pool php5-fcgi-staging01] child 8943, script '/home/ver/v1.3.62/public/index.php' (request: "GET /index.php") executing too slow (9.019635 sec), logging
[05-Jan-2022 10:40:29] NOTICE: child 8943 stopped for tracing
[05-Jan-2022 10:40:29] NOTICE: about to trace 8943
[05-Jan-2022 10:40:29] NOTICE: finished trace of 8943
[05-Jan-2022 10:41:11] WARNING: [pool php5-fcgi-staging01] child 8943, script '/home/ver/v1.3.62/public/index.php' (request: "GET /index.php") executing too slow (8.323565 sec), logging
[05-Jan-2022 10:41:11] NOTICE: child 8943 stopped for tracing
[05-Jan-2022 10:41:11] NOTICE: about to trace 8943
[05-Jan-2022 10:41:11] NOTICE: finished trace of 8943
[05-Jan-2022 10:41:19] WARNING: [pool php5-fcgi-staging01] child 28022, script '/home/ver/v1.3.62/public/index.php' (request: "GET /index.php") executing too slow (10.022734 sec), logging
[05-Jan-2022 10:41:19] NOTICE: child 28022 stopped for tracing
[05-Jan-2022 10:41:19] NOTICE: about to trace 28022
[05-Jan-2022 10:41:19] NOTICE: finished trace of 28022
[05-Jan-2022 10:42:05] WARNING: [pool php5-fcgi-staging01] child 6940, script '/home/ver/v1.3.62/public/index.php' (request: "GET /index.php") executing too slow (10.653465 sec), logging
[05-Jan-2022 10:42:05] NOTICE: child 6940 stopped for tracing
[05-Jan-2022 10:42:05] NOTICE: about to trace 6940
[05-Jan-2022 10:42:05] NOTICE: finished trace of 6940
[05-Jan-2022 10:46:10] WARNING: [pool php5-fcgi-staging01] child 32351, script '/home/ver/v1.3.62/public/index.php' (request: "GET /index.php") executing too slow (8.441833 sec), logging
[05-Jan-2022 10:46:10] NOTICE: child 32351 stopped for tracing
[05-Jan-2022 10:46:10] NOTICE: about to trace 32351
[05-Jan-2022 10:46:10] NOTICE: finished trace of 32351
[05-Jan-2022 11:28:21] NOTICE: Terminating ...
[05-Jan-2022 11:28:21] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
```

It's this, so I am thinking the 404 might be due to there being too much resources being used. How can I investigate further? Thanks

The stack is Nginx -> Varnish -> Apache -> PHP-FPM

I am thinking the cronjob might be the issue, is there a way to disable all cronjobs without stopping the browser requests from being served?